# How to rename attributes using xsl:perform-sort?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML document:

```
<graph>
  <v id="a"/>
  <v id="boo"/>
  <v id="boo"/>
  <v id="a"/>
</graph>
```

I'm trying to rename all `@id` attributes to unique numbers, which would represent the order in which attributes showed up in the document (actually, it may be any order, as long as the numbers I'll uniquely map to the textual values of the attributes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:variable name="sorted">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="@*">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="@*" priority="1">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="index-of(distinct-values($sorted), .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
<graph>
  <v id="1"/>
  <v id="2"/>
  <v id="2"/>
  <v id="1"/>
</graph>
```

But my XSL doesn't even compile (however a very similar approach works for modifying node text contents, not attributes).

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: If you get a compile-time error then it's rather important to tell us what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**Input XML**

```
<graph>
    <v id="a"/>
    <v id="boo"/>
    <v id="boo"/>
    <v id="a"/>
</graph>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abc', '123')"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="index-of(distinct-values(/graph/v/@id), .)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<graph>
  <v id="1"/>
  <v id="2"/>
  <v id="2"/>
  <v id="1"/>
</graph>
```

Comment: Good idea, but my real case is much more complicated: attribute values are longer than one character. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow this correctly, you are trying to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:variable name="sorted">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="/graph/v">
      <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="index-of(distinct-values($sorted/v/@id), .)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:

- The context of a global variable is the root node;
- Attributes must be children of some element'
- If you don't care about the order, then sorting is a waste of time, CPU cycles and electricity. And so is the repeated application of `distinct-values(`) on the same sequence.